# ¿Cómo puedo saber el ID de una ventana de alerta en Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, sharepoint

Buen día,
Estoy tratando de automatizar una ventana pero no tengo idea como saber cual es el ID de los campos: "nombre de usuario" y "contraseña", dado que con el Inspector del Firefox no puedo extraer dicho ID,

Les agradezco

[image: Imagen]

```
    package Modulos;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Normatividad {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://srvd-sp1:45002/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testNormatividad() throws Exception {
    // ERROR: Caught exception [unknown command [label]]
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx");
    Select UsuarioWindows = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ClaimsLogonSelector']")));
        UsuarioWindows.selectByValue("Windows");

    driver.findElement(By.id("viewlist69c42153-dcc4-4897-8c14-a3dbcf2f280a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='idHomePageNewItem']/span[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField")).sendKeys("Norma Selenium IDE");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Sector_cf99eb7b-0dfd-40ad-ad32-9ba27a3fedde_$DropDownChoice")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Sector_cf99eb7b-0dfd-40ad-ad32-9ba27a3fedde_$DropDownChoice"))).selectByVisibleText("Gas");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("TipoDeNorma_fcec88c5-96c6-4096-b3f0-753b15522dd1_$DropDownChoice"))).selectByVisibleText("Decreto");
    driver.findElement(By.id("NumeroDeLaNorma_7e332ac2-55cb-4ea2-9c48-b30bed65ae62_$NumberField")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("NumeroDeLaNorma_7e332ac2-55cb-4ea2-9c48-b30bed65ae62_$NumberField")).sendKeys("877765");
    driver.findElement(By.id("FechaDeLaNorma_b2916758-64de-488d-9b1b-478209e7a7c7_$DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DatePickerDiv > div.ms-datepickerouter > div.ms-quickLaunch > div.ms-picker-header > table.ms-picker-table > tbody > tr > td > a.ms-pagearrow-left > img.ms-pagearrow-left-icon")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("20170111")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("DescripcionDeLaNorma_c0f1e376-2baa-4425-8b69-483f1777ad1d_$TextField_inplacerte")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("DescripcionDeLaNorma_c0f1e376-2baa-4425-8b69-483f1777ad1d_$TextField_inplacerte")).sendKeys("Prueba automatizada con Selenium IDE");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='Ribbon.ListForm.Edit-title']/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile-Large']/span[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("onetidIOFile")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("onetidIOFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\rtalero\\Desktop\\tst-cloud.png");
    driver.findElement(By.id("attachOKbutton")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl48_g_83603d0e_fb89_4c30_a560_d43b3c5ffbfd_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"SGC\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Normatividad')])[2]")).click();
    // ERROR: Caught exception [unknown command [gotolabel]]
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hola @RafaelStef deberías agregar tu código, lo que has intentando hasta ahorita, algo que nos ayude a saber que camino estás tomando.

Comment: @RandallSandoval listo bro, adjunté el código, más precisamente es donde dice: Select UsuarioWindows = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ClaimsLogonSelector']")));
        UsuarioWindows.selectByValue("Windows");

Estoy haciendo una prueba automatizada paso por paso

Comment: Tengo entendido que esos diálogos son propios del sistema operativo. Si estás automatizando, revisa las llamadas http que se envían cuando te logueas (con el inspector) luego intenta recrearla con métodos post o get de tu librería java. Ahora, también puede ser que los parámetros que se envían en la petición que se genera después de dar aceptar, sean los nombres de los campos.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, la manera más sencilla de actuar con ese tipo de credenciales es incluirlas en la URL de eta manera:

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

Comment: Al ingresar esa linea de codigo: driver.get("admin:password123"); me sigue lanzando el mismo error

Comment: @RafaelStef En tu caso supongo que sería algo parecido driver.get("admin:password123@" + baseUrl + "/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx");